# Using Django taggit output is Id of tags insted of name.How can I change my output into tags names?

Tags: python, django

I have one field that is custom tag.

When I get that particular field from model and try to print all stored values in that field, It will displays as Id's of each value.

How can I get that values which I had stored as string.

- views.py

  ```
  def patfirst(request):
  if request.method == "GET":
     return render(request, 'personal/patfirst.html')

  if request.POST.get('Next'):
     newSymp = request.POST.get('newSymptom')
     didata = Disease.objects.all().values_list('symptoms')
     args = {'newSymp' : newSymp,'didata':didata}
     return render(request, 'personal/patfirst.html',args)
  ```
- models.py

  ```
  class TaggedSymptoms(TaggedItemBase):
       content_object = models.ForeignKey("Disease")

  class Disease(models.Model):
      did = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Disease Id', primary_key=True,default=0)
      dName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

      symptoms = TaggableManager(verbose_name='symptoms list', through=TaggedSymptoms)                
      symptoms.rel.related_name = "+"
  ```
- patfirst.html

  ```
    <h1>search disease</h1>
    <form method="post" action="#">
       {% csrf_token %}
       Enter Symptom: <input type="text" name="newSymptom"/><br><br>
       <h3>
           {% for s in didata %}
              {{ s }}
           {% endfor %}
       </h3>
       <input type="submit" value="Next" name="Next"/>
       <input type="submit" value="None of these" name="NoneOfThese"/>
     </form>
  ```

[output I got is like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mo0z.png)

Comment: Code? Input? Expected output?

Comment: Input: any symptom. Ex: fever   and output: all symptoms list will be taken  whose disease contains  fever symptom. Ex: dengue has symptoms like(fever,headache,joint pain) and flu has (fever,Muscles ache,headache). so, dengue and flu will be displayed as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you providing much detail, I can guess that you can do so by printing it this way.(provide more information in order to get a more precise answer)

```
tags = your_object.tags
for tag in tags:
    print tag, tag.your_string_field
```